# Gravar registro na tabela a cada acesso do usuário

Tags: php

Preciso criar um script que grave um log de ultimo acesso numa tabela, porém meu insert mas não está funcionando. Criei uma classe Acesso, onde o mesmo faz o login.

Se alguém puder me ajudar. Obrigado.

Minha classe de acesso:

```
class Acesso {

    public function run() {

        $html = '';

        Session::setValue('erro', '');

        switch (App::getAction()) {
            case 'logout':
                $this->logout();
                break;

            case 'validar':
                $this->validar();
                break;

            default:
                $html = $this->login();
                break;
        }

        return $html;
    }

    public function login() {

        $html_login = new Html();
        $html = $html_login->load('view/acesso.html');


        return $html;
    }

    public function validar() {

        $dados = Connection::select("SELECT login,senha,nome,departamento_id FROM users WHERE login='" . $_POST['usuario'] . "'");
        Connection::close();

        foreach ($dados as $reg):
            if ($_POST['senha'] == $reg['senha']):
                Session::setValue('logado', true);
                Session::setValue('departamento', $reg['departamento_id']);
                Session::setValue('nome', $reg['nome']);

            else:
                echo "<script>alert('Dados inválidos!'); location.href= 'index.php';</script>";
            endif;
        endforeach;

        $sql = "update log set user_id= user_id, user_data= user_data where id=" . App::$key;
                    $dados = Connection::exec($sql);

        header('Location: ' . URL);
    }

    public function logout() {

        Session::setValue('logado', false);
        header('Location: ' . URL);
    }

}
```

Quando executo, apresenta esse erro abaixo:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function exec() on a non-object in
```

Comment: não sei se entendi vc quer contar quantas vezes o usuario logou? ou fazer uma tabela de log cada vez que ele logar vc salva a data e a hora?

Comment: Quantas vezes o usuário logou.

Comment: Faz um select pra pegar o valor, salva em uma variavel e faz $variavel +1

Comment: Não sei como fazer, consegue me dar um exemplo?

Comment: Tente ser mais especifico, o que não está a funcionar?

Comment: Ele não grava o registro na tabela, e apresenta esse erro Fatal error: Call to a member function exec() on a non-object in

Comment: $sql = "update `users` set `acesso`= `acesso` + 1 where `login` = '" . $_POST['usuario'] . "'";
                    $dados2 = Connection::exec($sql);

Linhas do insert

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, para esse caso específico, primeiramente sugiro que você crie uma tabela especificamente pra isso.
Toda vez que você executa um Update, a paginação de dados do banco pode ficar meio "desorganizada" e dependendo o tamanho do seu sistema, isso pode ser um problema.

Porém, caso você queira manter como está, é necessário buscar o registro no banco de dados, executar o "+1" no PHP e depois executar o Update passando o objeto alterado. É só pra ter uma ideia, mas o exemplo seria tipo isso:

```
$count = $obj->TotalAcessos +1;
$sql = "update 'users' set 'acesso'= '" . $count . "'where id=" . App::$key;
$dados = Connection::exec($sql);
```

Se quiser seguir minha primeira sugestão, a tabela pode conter Id (autoincremento), IdUsuario e Data do Login.
Toda vez que alguém efetuar login, você insere nessa tabela.
Depois você poderá identificar quantas vezes ele fez login, por exemplo:

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM HistoricoLogin WHERE IdUsuario = 1
```

Além do fato de que, como você tem as datas salvas, você consegue saber a quantidade de acessos de um dia específico ou de um range de datas.

Comment: Não funcionou, porém acho melhor criar uma tabela de log mesmo. Vou tentar desenvolver algo.

Answer (score 0):

Nesse trecho

```
$sql = "update `users` set `acesso`= acesso + 1 where id=" . App::$key;
```

Troque por isso:

```
$sql = "update `users` set `acesso`= `acesso` + 1 where `login` = '" . $_POST['usuario'] . "'";
```

Comment: Não funcionou tbm :/